# Are there any known DC super metals besides Nth?

Tags: dc, metamaterials

Thinking about it, we know the *Marvel* universe, Comic, animated, TV and movie, has a *number* of cool super metals...

*Adamantium* has heavy molecular density and bonds, but light weight, is resistant to temp extremes, corrosives and even an atomic blast...

*Vibranium* absorbs and redirects kinetic energyeven from most light, heat and electricity... all things but sound. And it can be charged to a capacity that it can *expel* this energy as a wave or beam.

Even *Uru* is a mystical metal possibly made from star matter yet light, durable, and almost unbreakable which can channel, redirect, absorb and amplify magic. And no known corrosives can damage it...

But all *DC* has is Nth metal;: an *unnaturally* hard yet flexible ore which can amp up or *totally* disrupt all energy fields, from electromagnetic to sound to radioactive to gravitational to magical. It's amazingly versatile, making for very effective weapons and armor, and even vehicles.

Does DC have any *other* metals which can help even the odds? Nothing that suppresses power, or is almost unbreakable, or which enhances meta-human abilities? Nothing that reflects all light and concussive forces, but is weak to solvents? Nothing that vibrates at two separate levels, pushing those who hold it into another dimension?

If you know of any, please let me know. If possible, provide a visual example or reference to each. And yes, they can be *alien,* but *no, K-metals **don't count;** they take more affect Kryptonians due to the radiation, not their physical capabilities.

What are some other possible examples?

Comment: I kinda disagree with the duplicate in the sense that linked answer is not correct, mostly because being too old (Tenth metal is quite recent).

Comment: @dna but isn't Tenth metal just another name for Element X, and that was references back in 72?